# Eliminate row from data.frame based on partially duplicate values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a relatively large data.frame with 205K observations and 54 variables. This data.frame is the result of appending three different data.frames. The original data.frames all have the columns date, time, lat and lon, but each data.frame carries accessory information which i need to retain. In the final data.frame I have therefore sets of three rows where date, time, lat, lon, are exactly the same but the values of var1, var2 and so forth are different and some are NA. A simplified version of my data.frame could look like the following:

```
mydf
  var1 date time var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 lat lon
1    A    1    2    3    4    5    6    7   8   9
2    B    1    2 <NA> <NA> <NA>    6    7   8   9
3 <NA>    1    2 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   8   9
```

In particular, I would like highlight in my data.frame those sets of rows with the same date, time, lat and long, but only retain the ones where, as an instance, var1 is not NA so that the final data.frame should look like:

```
  var1 date time var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 lat lon
1    A    1    2    3    4    5    6    7   8   9
2    B    1    2 <NA> <NA> <NA>    6    7   8   9
```

I know that I can use the

```
distinct(mydf, ..., .keep_all = TRUE)
```

but I can't figure out to use the arguments properly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`:

First identify `duplicated` rows from top to bottom to get all the duplicated rows with the `select`ed variables. Then `filter` where this new variable is `TRUE` and where `var1` is other than `NA`:

```
library(dplyr)


mydf %>% mutate(dup = duplicated(select(., date, time, lat, lon)) | 
                      duplicated(select(., date, time, lat, lon), fromLast = TRUE)) %>% 
         filter(dup == TRUE & !is.na(var1))
```

Comment: Thank you David for your answer. The code does not work for my specific case. Once adjusting it for my data.frame, it works to an extent that it deletes all the rows where var1 = NA, irrespective of whether or not that specific row has a duplicate rowin the data.frame in terms of date, time, lat and lon.  Basically, it deletes the entire content of one of the original tables. Could you suggest any other approach? Thanks

Comment: As you said: "only retain the ones where, as an instance, var1 is not NA". The script I wrote gives the output you gave as expected. Could you then clarify the condition?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a less direct and most likely less elegant solution to deal with the duplicate rows in my specific data.frame by first adding a "datetime" column to all my data.frames, subsequently by "subtracting" one data.frame to another and finally by appending them toa final data.frame

```
#my data.frames
#df1
#df2

df1<- mutate(df1, datetime = paste(df1$date, df1$time)) #add a column "datetime" by concatenating the columns "date" and "time"
df2<- mutate(df2, datetime = paste(df2$date, df2$time)) #add a column "datetime" by concatenating the columns "date" and "time"

df1<-anti_join(df1, df2, by ="datetime") #delete from df1 those rows that occur in df2 based on the column "datedime"

df.f<-rbind.fill(df1, df2) #append the two data.frames in "df.f"
```

Possibly not the fastest approach but it works fine with my data.